# generating a vector saying how a list should be sorted in python

Tags: python, sorting, permutation

I want to generate a vector that tells me how a list should be sorted, so I can apply it to a list of labels associated with the list of objects. I know that it is possible in matlab, does something like this exist in python?

An example:

Suppose you have a list of binary digits `list1 = ['10100', '10101', '01010', '00010', '00100']` 
and a series of labels for the binary digits `colnames = ["A","B","C","D","E"]` using `list.sort()` I can sort list1 in place, but I want to know how that sorting was done, and then apply that permutation to the list of labels as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> listOne = ['10100', '10101', '01010', '00010', '00100']
>>> listTwo = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
>>> listThree = zip(listOne, listTwo)
>>> listThree.sort(key = lambda x : x[0])
>>> listThree
[('00010', 'D'), ('00100', 'E'), ('01010', 'C'), ('10100', 'A'), ('10101', 'B')]
>>> listOneSorted, listTwoSorted = zip(*listThree)
>>> listOneSorted
('00010', '00100', '01010', '10100', '10101')
>>> listTwoSorted
('D', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'B')
```

Or a one liner summing all the above up.

```
>>> listOneSorted, listTwoSorted = zip(*sorted(zip(listOne, listTwo), key = lambda x : x[0]))
```

Comment: Then you could always do `list1_sorted, labels_sorted = zip(*listThree)`

Comment: Yup. Was just adding that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just this! Though as a followup, I wonder if there is a way to do this same idea in radix sort (the original algorithm i am trying to implement takes advantage of the fact that radix sort is O(n) to sort, while sort.() is O(nlogn).